# How to open DOM Element with Featherlight on Page Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm having trouble getting a Featherlight modal window to show content on page load.

https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#usage

https://jsfiddle.net/axxdy4we/

**Open Featherlight DOM with Link**

```
<a href="#" class="my-content" data-featherlight="<p>My Content</p>">Open some DOM in lightbox</a>
```

This link loads html content from the `data-featherlight` attribute

Clicking the link will load "My Content".

**On Page Load**

```
$.featherlight($('.my-content'), {});
```

This only loads whats between the `<a>` tags, "`Open some DOM in lightbox`".

How to call "My Content" from the `data-featherlight` attribute on page load?

I need to have the html inside the `data-featherlight`, not outside in a div.

I thought it might be something like

```
$('.my-content').featherlight();

$('.my-content').featherlight.current();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `.featherlight()` on your content to ensure that the modal window is configured, and then use jQuery to `.click()` it right after the page loads:

```js
$('.my-content').featherlight().click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/release/featherlight.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="my-content" data-featherlight="<p>My Content</p>">
  Open some DOM in lightbox
</a>
```